# Как воспроизводить файл не дожидаясь полной загрузки

Tags: javascript, php

Есть вот такой код:

```
let au = document.getElementById('audioplayer');

function getAudio()
{


    var Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    Request.responseType = 'blob';
    Request.open('GET', 'response.php?audio=true');
    //Передаёт правильный заголовок в запросе
    Request.onreadystatechange = function () {//Вызывает функцию при смене состояния.
        if (Request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && Request.status === 200) {                    
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                au.src = reader.result;
            };
           reader.readAsDataURL(Request.response);


        }
    }
    Request.send();
}

 $(document).ready(getAudio);

au.onended = getAudio;
```

Тут php script возвращает аудио файл, декодированный из base64. Проблема заключается в том что при загрузке следующего файла(они постоянно меняются), возникает задержка при загрузке файла. И файл пока полностью не загрузится, воспроизведение не начинается. Нужно сделать чтоб файл как бы начинал проигрываться не загрузившись до конца.
[image: javascript]

Comment: Ооо... это, пожалуй, надо смотреть в сторону потоковой загрузки и обработки файлов

Comment: а есть какие-то ссылки, а в гугле не могу ничё найти..

Comment: Не, к сожалению, не подскажу(

Comment: Вам нужно загружать следующий файл, не дожидаясь, когда проиграется текущий. Грубо говоря, скачиваем сразу два файла. Когда они скачались, начинаем воспроизводить. Воспроизвёлся первый, запускаем второй, начинаем скачивать третий, и т. д.